# Modify the photo description using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm able to publish a photo with description on Facebook using Graph API. 
But, i figured out that i can't delete it using Graph API, as of now. But, is there any way to modify the description of the existing photo?

I tried many API calls, but no success yet. Is this achievable or so far, such functionality doesn't exist?

Thank You

Comment: No, there is currently no way to delete or update photos via an app.

Comment: Ah! Facebook should have it. Anyways... thank you for confirming it.

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the photos that are uploaded via our APP. we can use the ID of photo to delete it.